# Parameter value `onClick` changed

Tags: javascript, php, html, anchor

I have a problem with `javascript`.

Let's say I have `javascript` function like this:

```
<script>
    function show_popup(id) {
        alert(id);
    }
</script>
```

**EDIT**

On the other hand, I have an anchor which call that function:

```
<?php
    ...
    $rs5 = $db->Execute("SELECT * FROM students");

    foreach ($rs5 as $roww) {
         echo "<tr $clr onMouseOver=this.bgColor='gold'; onMouseOut=this.$clr;  >"
             ."<td>".$roww[name]."&nbsp;</td>"
             ."<td><a href='javascript:void(0);' title='Show' onClick='show_popup(".$roww[id].");'> SHOW </a></td>"
             ."</tr>";
    }
    ...
?>
```

When I click that anchor, it'll show `alert` which says whatever in `show_popup` parameter, right?

Now, I have a problem that sometimes, the alert content and the parameter on `onClick` **did not** equal (changed). 
(Ex.: `... onClick='show_popup(547);' ...`, the alert shows: `987`)

**UPDATED:**

Here's a screenshot between `alert` and the inspect element `onClick` inline (the function name is `detail_popup` which is the same as `show_popup` above):

[image]

How can i fixed it?

Thank you so much for any answer.

Comment: Is this is the complete code?

Comment: @user2181397 actually no... the parameter `onClick` is filled with data which I get from database.

Comment: Would need to see more of the codes

Comment: my two cents . I will create a new data attribute & will fill it's value with the database values & on click i i wll pass this value

`<a href='javascript:void(0);' onClick='show_popup(this.data-attribute);' data-value="value from database" title='Show'> SHOW </a>`

Comment: @andremcgruder code updated.

Comment: @user2181397 code updated.

Comment: @joshua14 so this anchor tags are dynamically created?

Comment: @user2181397 dynamically depends on how many row(s) returned from `select` query

Comment: When you view the page source in the browser, do the inline `onclick` attributes contain the correct values?

Comment: @nnnnnn yes.. that's why I asked here XD

Comment: Well...does that mean you could copy the output HTML into a demo so that we can see the problem behaviour for ourselves?

Comment: @nnnnnn try this on jsfiddle:
<a href='javascript:void(0);' onClick='show_popup(0000003520316);' title='Show'> SHOW </a>


<script>
function show_popup(id) {
    alert(id);
}
</script>

it'll give the same problem

Comment: Yes, the edit provided the information needed to explain the problem (the leading zeros). If the leading zeros are important you probably want to use it as a string rather than a number.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

As i can see in your console. HTML output is:

```
<a href='javascript:void(0);' onClick='show_popup(0000003520316);' title='Show'> SHOW </a>
```

In *onclick()* function number is started with **00**** which denotes the number will convert to **Octal** number thats why you are getting wrong output send number without **00** you will correct answer.

Comment: *"with 00****"* - Note that it only takes a *single* leading zero in a numeric literal to get octal.

Comment: Yes. If you test any number which start with 0 it will auto convert to Octal.